# Why does the list of recent contributions contain exactly two boxes?

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex, output-routine

In the transcript of

```
\nonstopmode
\tenrm
\vsize=2cm

\output={\shipout\vbox{
  \showlists
  \unvbox255
}}

\hbox{blah}
\hbox{blah}
\hbox{blah}
\hbox{blah}
\hbox{blah}
\hbox{blah}
\hbox{blah}
\hbox{blah}
\hbox{blah}

\bye
```

the `\showlists` in my output routine gives me in each except the last iteration:

```
### recent contributions:
\glue(\baselineskip) 5.05556
\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x18.88895
.\tenrm b
.\tenrm l
.\tenrm a
.\tenrm h
\glue(\baselineskip) 5.05556
\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x18.88895
.\tenrm b
.\tenrm l
.\tenrm a
.\tenrm h
prevdepth 0.0
```

Why are there two of the `hbox`-es and not three or one (which I'd expect most)?

Comment: Why not? Probably one `\hbox` had been moved before deciding the page break and so it has been put back in the recent contributions. It's hard to diagnose with a system font, as they tend to be different from system to system. Try with a standard distribution font, so that everybody can test the same setting (I don't get your log, for example).

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the MVL->page-builder->output-routine sequence. I understand that usually the page-builder (and subsequent the output-routine) is run between paragraphs. Since here are no paragraphs, what is triggering the run? About the font: Such as `\tenrm`? Updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

TeX exercises the page builder (TeXbook, page 281) also when it finds a `<box>` in vertical mode (page 282).

When the page builder is exercised, something from the recent contribution list is carried to the main vertical list, in order to see whether a page must be ejected. In your case, `\tracingpages=1` gives

```
%% goal height=56.9055, max depth=4.0
% t=10.0 g=56.9055 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=22.0 g=56.9055 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=34.0 g=56.9055 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=46.0 g=56.9055 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=58.0 g=56.9055 b=* p=0 c=*
```

The page break calculations show that a page break is taken between boxes 4 and 5, so that box 5 is put back in the list of recent contributions, where box 6 is already there, because otherwise TeX wouldn't have known that a legitimate break point was possible.

If instead of `blah` we put `blah1`, `blah2` and so on in the boxes, the recent contribution list shows indeed

```
### recent contributions:
\glue(\baselineskip) 5.05556
\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x23.88896
.\tenrm b
.\tenrm l
.\tenrm a
.\tenrm h
.\tenrm 5
\glue(\baselineskip) 5.05556
\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x23.88896
.\tenrm b
.\tenrm l
.\tenrm a
.\tenrm h
.\tenrm 6
prevdepth 0.0
```

Comment: When it finds a *what*?

Comment: @AndreKR A `<box>`; sorry.

Comment: Why didn't this already happen after box 5?

Comment: @AndreKR Until box 6 doesn't appear into the recent contribution list, TeX doesn't know that there's a legitimate break point after box 5.

Comment: I see, and then again why it doesn't wait until after box 7 to see if there is another possible breakpoint after box 6? Because it dit already find that the breakpoint after box 5 is bad?

Comment: @AndreKR TeX finds the possibility of breaking the page after box 5 when a page is still not complete; so when it sees a legitimate break point, it suspends its work and does its page breaking calculations; box 5 doesn't fit, so it's sent again to the list of recent contributions; then the page is ejected and work resumes.